# RS (NOR) flip flop stuck at undefined

Tags: logic-gates

I'm trying to make an asynchronic automata which outputs every other impulse (any amount of 1's) from input ( 0 in any other state).Heres states table:

```
Q1Q2\X  0   1   Y
00      00  01  0
01      11  01  0
11      11  10  0
10      00  10  1
```

My functions are:

```
R1=Q2'X'
S1=Q2X'
R2=Q1X
S2=XQ1'
```

Desiered output:
[image]

My output:
[image]

My scheme:
[image]

I've also tried usig NAND based RS and using only Q1Q2 functions. Both had same result as above.

### Fixed

I need to force it into one of defined states (00) by adding additional inputs (a1..4). After that i set those inputs to vaules which won't interfere and it worked exactly as desinged. Hope that helps if anyone else has that problem.

Output:
[image]

Scheme:
[image]

Comment: In a simulator, flip-flops will start in an undefined state, unless explicitly set or cleared.  When you toggle a flip-flop that is in an undefined state, it will still be in an undefined state.

Answer (score 1):

State machines, *by definition*, require a clock. A state machine transitions from its current state to the next state on each tick of a clock; without a clock, there's no way to determine when a transition should occur.

You can't build a state machine out of asynchronous logic. And you definitely can't implement a function like "output every other 1" without a clock -- how is a circuit supposed to tell the difference between "1" and "11" and "1111111" without a clock to "count" the 1s?

Comment: By every other 1 i meant impulses. Doesn't matter how long they are. And if You say that's not possible to do than I'm in bad luck. My professor said to build it using asynchronous logic.

Comment: We call that positive edge, not "every other one".

Answer (score 0):

If you're designing a FF you missed the clock input, as stated by @duskwuff on his answer.
You said that you need to build an asynchronous automata, so you will need, in fact, the clock input for every FF, despite the second clock coming from the first FF and so on, you need to provide the control signal.